# Problems with triangulation in PolyK

Tags: three.js, polygon, triangulation

I did some triangulation tasks with the library **[PolyK](http://polyk.ivank.net/)**. Just for comparison purposes for my simple polygons.
I have  a Polygon with 7 vertices. But I get with this library only 9 indexes == 3 triangles that is to less I guess.

In the following code you see my implemention of PolyK.js in THREE.js

```
var pts3 = [];
var ids2 = PolyK.Triangulate(pts3);
for (var k = 0; k < ids2.length; k+=3) 
{
 geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(ids2[k], ids2[k + 1], ids2[k + 2]));
}
```

---

**My points array:**

(7 points with x and y value)

```
var points = [
    158.56000000005588, 336.73000000044703,
    158.60000000009313, 335.21999999973923,
    161.589999999851, 335.3099999995902,
    161.7799999997951, 329.820000000298,
    155.52000000001863, 329.62000000011176,
    155.29999999981374, 336.62999999988824,
    158.56000000005588, 336.73000000044703
];
```

**This is the current result:**

[image]

**This is the expected result:**

[image]

Is there something wrong regarding the usage of PolyK in the source code?

Comment: Can you share the data for your points and an image of the expected result?

Comment: The data of my points is this kind of array : 
Array[14, x,y] = [158.56000000005588,336.73000000044703,158.60000000009313,335.21999999973923,161.589999999851,335.3099999995902,161.7799999997951,329.820000000298,155.52000000001863,329.62000000011176,155.29999999981374,336.62999999988824,158.56000000005588,336.73000000044703]                                                                                         it should look like: ![Polygon](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5AUL4-roeC4cS1yWkRuVU1KM3c/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: I see only 7 points, not 14. Is that correct?

Comment: oh jeah my mistake sorry for that. But also I get only 3 triangles if I use other libaries like earcut I get 4!

Comment: you need to share all relevant information in your question so people can reproduce the issue. Read also [here for more information](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please update your question with the correct data.

Answer (score 0):

These are the points:

```
4 _______________ 3
 |               |
 |               |
 |               |
 |               |
 |               |
 |        _______|
 |       |1       2
 |_______|
5        0/6
```

I tested in [a fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/r8fvx5w4/) and it seems to work like you said.
I get result:

```
[5, 6, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3]
```

It is the same incorrect result as you showed in your drawing.

At first I thought removing the duplicated point ( 0 is same as 6 ) would solve the issue, but that also gives a incorrect result.

I would suggest using a different library like [earcut](https://github.com/mapbox/earcut) or [poly2tri](https://github.com/r3mi/poly2tri.js).

Check also [this triangulation adapter/library on GitHub that I made for three.js](https://github.com/Wilt/three.js_triangulation). It might be useful for you.

Comment: OK thanks for your efforts. So I guess in my case it is useless to use PolyK -> I will mention this in my work... Actually with earcut I get very good results

Comment: results : [triangulation-results](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5AUL4-roeC4T2FZeG14YkR3Zkk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Moehre if you check [here with poly2tri](http://r3mi.github.io/poly2tri.js/) with these points it also works correctly: `158.56000000005588, 336.73000000044703,
158.60000000009313, 335.21999999973923,
161.589999999851, 335.3099999995902,
161.7799999997951, 329.820000000298,
155.52000000001863, 329.62000000011176,
155.29999999981374, 336.62999999988824`. Earcut is great, reliable and fast.

Comment: I am actually trying with the original algorithm from THREE.ShapeUtils. But an error occurs: **building.js:144 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'triangulateShape' of undefined**  I included shape.js already. Do you know what is missing?

Comment: @Moehre Seems like you didn't load `THREE.ShapeUtils`. Are you sure you included `src/extras/ShapeUtils.js` when loading your scripts?

Comment: Oh I forgot this but still the same error. But now this error occurs: **THREE.ShapeUtils: Unable to triangulate polygon! in triangulate()** I am using this call `THREE.ShapeUtils.triangulateShape(shape2Points.shape, shape2Points.holes);`

Comment: When I delet the first point in the shape geometry it works.                                  `var shape2 = new THREE.Shape([
                 //{ x: 0, y: 0 },
                 { x: 158.56000000005588,   y: 336.73000000044703 },
                 { x: 158.60000000009313,  y: 335.21999999973923 },
                 { x: 161.589999999851,   y: 335.3099999995902 },
                 { x: 161.7799999997951, y: 329.820000000298 },
                ...
                ].map(function(pt) {
                     return new THREE.Vector2(pt.x, pt.y);
                 }));
`

Comment: @Moehre, Yes because duplicate points are not allowed, the first and last point should not be the same vertex.

Comment: OK thanks a lot. But the next stept will be to integrate these triangles in THREE.js. For other libraries e.g. earcut I used a loop to create the face. How can I handle this problem here? Can you give me an advice? thanks a lot

Comment: Ok I just created a variable `var faces = THREE.ShapeUtils.triangulateShape(shape2Points.shape, shape2Points.holes);` all triangles are inside after this I use this kind of loop: `for (var i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) {geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(faces[i][0],faces[i][1],faces[i][2]));}`. It works fine. But at the end when I wanna add this Mesh objekt to the scene it is written **THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D. undefined** What does it mean? everything looks fine!

Comment: @Moehre This falls outside the scope of your current question. If you want help with it I propose you close this question and ask a new question.